# How to Show Google's `People also search for` in Chrome

Tags: google-search

I noticed recently that if I search for something in Google, click on one of the links, and go back to the search results, then a new box entitled `People also search for` appears below the search result I clicked on. Is it possible to show this box without clicking and going back? I am using Google Chrome for my browser. I am using a laptop, not smartphone.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible because Google uses fact that you are visiting a specific website to give recommendations to you. However, sometimes, a box saying "People Also Ask:" which is what you might be looking for. This feature doesn't always appear because it's still a relatively new feature.